# I'm getting this error when I'm trying to deploy the app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
remote:        error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/loader-utils/-/loader-utils-1.4.0.tgz: Integrity check failed for "loader-utils" (computed integrity doesn't match our records, got "sha512-qH0WSMBtn/oHuwjy/NucEgbx5dbxxnxup9s4PVXJUDHZBQY+s0NWA9rJf53RBnQZxfch7euUui7hpoAPvALZdA== sha1-xXm140yzSxp07cbB+za/o3HVphM=")
```

remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.